# Unable to access Spring boot port when deployed to azure service fabric

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-service-fabric

When following this tutorial -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-java-spring-boot

The first portion of it works correctly (deploying to a local azure instance) but when I attempt to deploy it to an azure instance I get one large headache. I have done the following:

1. Set 8080 endpoint in servicemanifest.xml
2. LB rule for 8080 internal and external
3. Probe on 8080
4. I can access the service by going to port 8080 of the external IP of the LB itself.
5. I CANNOT access the service by going to [Service Fabric FQDN]:8080

I am absolutely stumped on why this is not working. I am using a secured servicefabric cluster in azure, deployment succeeds and it lists the app as healthy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! The instructions are definitely outdated but I have no idea what i could be missing.

Azure Service Fabric Stats:
2 nodetypes, 10 nodes (5 and 5) spring boot app is running on node 2 for some reason
Port 8080 LB and probe rules are on both node LBs
Ubuntu 16 is the OS type.
Cluster is secured by certificate

Any help whatsoever is appreciated!

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, looks like some others are also having issues with this doc. Can you leave this feedback on the doc itself so we can investigate and get it updated ASAP? If you scroll to the bottom of the doc you will see an option to leave documentation feedback.

Comment: If you can access the service from the external IP and not from the cluster FQDN, I would guess that you are trying to access the wrong FQDN, because you have 2 node types, if you look the list of load balancers on azure portal you will see 2 LB, you should try the FQDN of the other LB to see if solves your problem